# Entry Point Not Found Exception when i create and display Window object

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I've developed of software which consists, in a first configuration window which parse a ini file at his startup.
Using C# with WPF library.

If parsing it is correct the window is closed immediately and a second window is displayed.

The application runs correctly on Windows 8.

When i run the application on a Windows 7 PC a ENTRY POINT NOT FOUND EXCEPTION it is thrown. Following the code which throws exception from configuration window.

```
if(parse()){ //parse() returns true if it is correct
   MainWindow w = new MainWindow(); //here where the exception is thrown
   w.Show();
   Close();
}
```

I've made the following attempts:

1. I've tried the following procedure, but it did not work:
   http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/exe-entry-point-not-found/5b0866c1-8e45-457e-a83c-651c1fd307cc.
2. I've tried to develop a new WPF project, with two window.
   In the start up window i've added a simple button which display the second window, in the same way as shown. And it runs correctly.

I suspect that in my project something is wrong.
And the entry point of the window that i'm trying to display is not well defined, but i'm not able what exaclty is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Build -> Configuration Manager -> Acitve solution platform -> New -> x86 (instead of x64) This helped to me.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but in my project i'm using x64 library. I can't compile with x86.